# Valgrind in C to find if there is no leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

Using Valgrind to find if there is no leaks. I found these two commands online but what is the different? Is there a different Valgrind command other than these two that is better/correct?

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./program
```

Or

```
valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./program
```

Comment: Did you read the man page?  What didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

`man valgrind`

> -v, --verbose
>
> Be more verbose. Gives extra information on various aspects of your program, such as: the shared objects loaded, the suppressions used, the progress of the instrumentation and execution engines, and warnings about
>              unusual behaviour. Repeating the option increases the verbosity level.
>
> --leak-check= [default: summary]
>
> When enabled, search for memory leaks when the client program finishes. If set to summary, it says how many leaks occurred. *If set to full or yes, each individual leak will be shown in detail and/or counted as an error,
>              as specified by the options --show-leak-kinds and --errors-for-leak-kinds.*